# Checked button styles won't display in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, button

First timer here!

**CSS, according to client specs:**

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #B8B7B8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 4em;
  margin: 25px 2px 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 4em;
}

button:active,
button:checked,
button:focus,
button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5pt #068985;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5pt #068985;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

The actual buttons are just plain old HTML `<buttons></button>`s.
Works fine in other browsers, but for some reason Firefox has me stumped.

**Does anyone know how to keep the border on a clicked button?**
It works for `:hover`, but that's about it.
And yes, I have searched the for a solution high and low.

Many thanks!

***Side quest*** - *if anyone knows how to create a space between the button and its custom outline when selected then I will write an honorary blog in your name!*

Comment: The `HTMLButtonElement` does not have a `:checked` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement

Comment: *create a space between the button and its custom outline* Not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve checked feature on click by adding class to the button (div for space). Also, you can achieve adding space between button and custom outline by adding parent div and set the border to parent div.

I have created jsfiddle here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ajm5wnos/32/

```js
var checked=false;

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", (elem)=>{
   event.target.parentNode.classList.remove("checked");
    checked= !checked;
 if(checked){
   event.target.parentNode.classList.add("checked");
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #B8B7B8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 4em;
}

#buttonParent{
  padding:2px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.checked{
  padding:2px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5pt #068985;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5pt #068985;
  outline: none;
}
#buttonParent:active,
#buttonParent:focus,
#buttonParent:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5pt #068985;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5pt #068985;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonParent">
  <button type="button" id="myButton">Button</button>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank so much Nimitkumar!

Comment: Can you please accept my solution if it helps you?  ;)